# SWT Problem with MouseTrackListener and Shell

Tags: eclipse, swt

I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in and I have a problem which is reproduced here:

```
    popup = new Shell(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(), SWT.TOOL );
    popup.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Text text = new Text(popup, SWT.MULTI | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    text.setBackground(new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(), 255, 255, 204));
    text.addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackListener() { 
       public void mouseHover(MouseEvent e) { 
       }    
       public void mouseExit(MouseEvent e) { 
          popup.dispose();   
       }    
       public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent e) { 
       } 
    });
popup.setSize(200, 100);
text.setText("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
popup.open();
```

As you can see I'm creating a shell and putting a Textbox inside it and putting it all across the shell. Then I attach a MouseTrackListener to the shell. The events don't fire (as in when I hover in the shell "mouseHover" is not printed etc). When I remove the Textbox the events fire. Can anyone tell me where the problem lies please? I don't want to attach a listener to the textbox but to the shell. I'll really appreciate the help because I've been trying to trace it for quite some time now.

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Comment: Any ideas please? I'm open to alternative implementations...

Comment: Please see this answer (which could also help here): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10825659/305973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kind person from the Eclipse SWT mailing list gave me this solution:

```
text.forceFocus();
           text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

                       @Override
                       public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                               shell.dispose();
                       }

           });
```

It's not exactly 100% what I wanted (since it seems that what I want can't be easily achieved) but it's great still. Hope it helps anyone who encounters the same problem.

Regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

I have a 'better' solution - depending on your preference.

Set the text to be 1 or 2 pixels smaller all round than the shell it is in.  The shell thus offers a border effect around the text.

Set the mouseExit on the shell.

This will give the correct behaviour - with one terrible problem.  As the mouse enters the text+shell combo, a mouseExit is generated by the mouse leaving the shell into the text box.

I have set a flag (boolean mouseIn_flag) which is first false.  On a mouseExit it is set true.  If it is true on mouseExit - shell.close() ;

The effect is that it ignores the first mouseExit, and allows the mouse into the text.  It performs a shell close when the mouse exits the text (and thus enters the shell) and then exits the shell.

Since the shell is only a one/two pixel border around the text, the user would have to work hard at strange movements to incorrectly trigger these events.